# Can't set focus on Device Manager window after connecting using Pywinauto

Tags: python, windows-10, pywinauto, device-manager

I've tried several ways to get the focus placed on the device manager window in Windows 10.  I have a lot of notes in the code snippet so I can keep track of what I've tried.  I'm able to open device manager but can't seem to focus on it.  I've tried things I've seen on stackoverflow, Youtube, and Google.

```
from pywinauto import Application, keyboard, mouse, findwindows
import time

# app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'mmc devmgmt.msc') # mmc.exe spawns a child process
# app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe') # connect to a child one
#
# '''
# The way Device Manager is opened causes a popup to display.  The popup states:
#     You are logged on as a standard user. You can view device settings in Device
#     Manager, but you must be logged on as an administrator to make changes.
#     ** Opening it this way, I can't Uninstall devices.  It has to be opened a different way. **
# '''
# dlgBox = app.DeviceManager.child_window(title="OK", auto_id="2", control_type="Button").wrapper_object()
# dlgBox.click_input() # Click on the OK button
#
# menuView = app.DeviceManager.child_window(title="View", control_type="MenuItem").wrapper_object()
# menuView.click_input() # Clicks the View menu item
# keyboard.send_keys('w') # Press w to select Show hidden devices

# Opening this way I can Uninstall devices
keyboard.send_keys("{LWIN down}" "r" "{LWIN up}") # Press the Winows key and R to open the Run dialog
keyboard.send_keys("devmgmt.msc" "{ENTER}") # Type devmgmt.msc into the Run dialog then press enter

'''
Right click Accessibility Insights for Windows and select Run Elevated with Defendpoint.
With Device Manager open, hover the mouse over the title bar.
Pause Live Inspect.
Select window 'Device Manager' to see all of its elements.
ProcessID = 23356, open Task Manager and look at Details, sort by PID.  23356 belongs to MMC.exe
'''
className = 'MMCMainFrame'
name = 'Device Manager'

# The pritn statements are for troubleshooting along the way, remove once working.
time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second to make sure window is open, without it was happening too fast and would sometimes error.
mywin = findwindows.find_window(active_only=True, class_name=className, title_re=name)
print("Device Manager handle = " + str(mywin)) # this is the handle for the window

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(handle=mywin)
print("app = " + str(app))

# Select View from the menu options then press the w key to select Show hidden devices
# menuView = app.DeviceManager.child_window(title="View", control_type="MenuItem")
# menuView.click_input() # Clicks the View menu item
# keyboard.send_keys('w') # Type w to select Show hidden devices

win = app.window(title_re=name)
print("win = " + str(win))

dlg = app[name]
print("dlg = " + str(dlg))

'''
I can open Device Manager but nothing I have tried is giving the window focus so I can't do anything else.
'''

# *** This is where I simply try to maximize the windows to see if I have the focus set. ***
# Maximize the Device Manager window
# maxWindow = app.DeviceManager.child_window(title="Maximize", control_type="Button")
# maxWindow.click_input() # Click the maximize button
```

I've tried opening Device Manager this way:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'mmc devmgmt.msc') # mmc.exe spawns a child process
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe') # connect to a child one
```

That does indeed open it but it opens in a way that I can't uninstall any devices.

I discovered that I can open it this way (this is currently how I'm opening it).

```
keyboard.send_keys("{LWIN down}" "r" "{LWIN up}") # Press the Windows key and R to open the Run dialog
keyboard.send_keys("devmgmt.msc" "{ENTER}") # Type devmgmt.msc into the Run dialog then press enter
```

Then I get the handle of the device manager window.
`mywin = findwindows.find_window(active_only=True, class_name=className, title_re=name)`
The connect to it, or at least I thought so.
`app = Application(backend="uia").connect(handle=mywin)`

Comment: The child process is spawned as Administrator, but `python.exe` may run not as Administrator. Please make sure you run the script (or `cmd.exe` or IDE) as Administrator.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I set cmd.exe to run as admin.  I still get the same error.  I'm still learning how to use Stack Overflow.  I tried to post the entire error but it was too many characters.  I believe this error is caused by not having the focus of the window.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\U264245\Downloads\GUI Automation with Python\venv\Device Manager Code Trial 2.py", line 59, in <module>
    maxWindow.click_input() # Click the maximize button